# Sorry, PowerPoint can't read <file name.>.pptx error when trying to open a powerpoint autorecovery file

Tags: macos, ms-office, keynote, file, zip

I was working on a powerpoint today, and then my document wouldn't let me save, and I ended up overwriting the file with a blank presentation. I don't remember the details of how that happened, but freaked out a perused the internet on how to get my old presentation back.

After hours of searching, and using hidden file finder programs, I found what seemed to be the autosaved versions of my presentation. However, I could not open them in the folder (Which was in library), and when I moved them to another folder (documents) I would get this error after selecting "repair" [image]

From this error:[image]

I tried solutions such as turning the file into a .key, and even a .zip and looking for my slides. I couldn't see my slides in the .zip version (which was a pain to unzip alone, needed The unarchiver, which eventually stopped opening the zip files), but sometimes when converting it back to a .pptx, I would see the first slide of my powerpoint as the picture representing the file in finder, indicating to me that at least the FIRST slide was present (and probably the others).

Any advice on how I can salvage my hours of work so I don't have to restart the powerpoint? Thank you so much!